# $C(\{0\} \times [0,1])$ is isomorphic to $C([0,1]\times [0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X=\{0\} \times [0,1]$ and $Y=[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Let $f\in C(X)$ and define $g(s,t)=f(0,t)$ for all $(s,t)\in Y$. Then $(s_n,t_n)\to (s,t)$ implies $g(s_n,t_n)=f(0,t_n)\to f(0,t)$ due to continuity of $f$. Hence $g\in C(Y)$.

Conversely, for every $f \in C(Y)$, the function $f|_X \in C(X)$.

> Does this mean that $C(X)$ is isomorphic to $C(Y)$?

Comment: First, "isomorphic" requires some sort of structure. What is the structure you are giving these sets? Second, you maps are not inverses of each other: the restriction map is not even injective: two different functions may have the same restriction to $X$. So why would you think that the existence of maps going in both directions somehow, by itself, yield an "isomorphism"?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin One of the maps is a left inverse of the other -- I think the mistake was thinking this implied they were two-sided inverses.  (And at least when you're dealing with finite dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension, this would imply isomorphism, but of course it doesn't here.)

Comment: @KyleMiller: But there is no structure specified, and no attempt to check if the functions respect that structure; right now they are just functions between two sets. And even if we think these are meant to be functional spaces, they would be infinite dimensional, and you would need to prove continuity relative to some norm, since they are almost never considered as just plain vanilla vector spaces. Of course we both know that, but why is the OP trying to make us *guess*, instead of telling us what he's doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the projection function $\pi:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to \{0\}\times [0,1]$ defined by $\pi(s,t)=(0,t)$ and the inclusion function $\iota:\{0\}\times [0,1]\to[0,1]\times[0,1]$ defined by $\iota(0,t)=(0,t)$.  The function $\pi$ is a surjection and $\iota$ is an injection.  Furthermore, $\pi\circ\iota:\{0\}\times[0,1]\to\{0\}\times[0,1]$ is an isomorphism, which is to say $\pi$ is a left inverse to $\iota$.

Whenever you have a continuous function $h:X\to Y$, you get an induced map $h^*:C(Y)\to C(X)$ defined by $h^*(f) = f\circ h$ for all $f\in C(Y)$.  This $h^*$ "pulls back" the domain of a function along $h$.

Your first construction, creating a function $g$ from an $f\in C(\{0\}\times[0,1])$, corresponds to $g=\pi^*(f) \in C([0,1]\times[0,1])$.  The second construction, restriction of $f\in C([0,1],[0,1])$, corresponds to $f|_X = \iota^*(f)\in C(\{0\}\times[0,1])$.

Since we have that $\pi\circ\iota=\operatorname{id}$, we can check that this implies $\iota^*\circ\pi^* = \operatorname{id}$.  That is, the following composition is the identity:
$$ C(\{0\}\times[0,1] ) \xrightarrow{\pi^*} C([0,1]\times [0,1]) \xrightarrow{\iota^*} C(\{0\}\times[0,1] ) $$
In particular, this means that $\pi^*$ is injective and $\iota^*$ is surjective.  This is all we know.

For the two function spaces to be isomorphic from this, we would need these to be isomorphisms.  However, we can easily see that $\iota^*$ is not injective.  Consider $f:[0,1]\times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(s,t)=s$.  Then $\iota^*(f) = f\circ \iota$, which is the function defined by $(0,t)\mapsto 0$.  This is to say that a nonzero function is in the kernel of $\iota^*$.